# Android Studio - Java - Previous Acvtivity gets loaded when FireStore Realtime Database is updated somehow?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

As the title states, somehow my activity5 loads the previous activity4 when the realtime database is updated.. and I can not figure out why because there's no call to activity4 anywhere within activity5.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();



    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);

    roomName = extras.getString("roomName");

    player = preferences.getString("player", "");
    playerHost = preferences.getString("playerHost", "");
    playerGuest = preferences.getString("playerGuest", "");

    questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);

    score2 = database.getReference("/rooms" + "/" + roomName + "/players" + "/player2" + "/score");

    int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(questions.length);
    String randomName = questions[randomIndex];

    if(player.equals(roomName) && !executed){
        yikes = database.getReference("/rooms" + "/" + roomName + "/questions" + "/question2" +"/question");
        a1a = database.getReference("/rooms" + "/" + roomName + "/questions" + "/question2" + "/answerA");
        score1 = database.getReference("/rooms" + "/" + roomName + "/players" + "/player1" + "/score");
        counter = database.getReference("/rooms" + "/" + roomName + "/questions" + "/counter");

        executed = true;
        counter.setValue("2");


        if("What is the rarest M and M color?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q1a);
            button2.setText(q1b);
            button3.setText(q1c);
            button4.setText(q1d);

            correctAnswer = button.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q1a);

        } else if("In a website browser address bar, what does “www” stand for?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q2b);
            button2.setText(q2c);
            button3.setText(q2d);
            button4.setText(q2a);

            correctAnswer = button4.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q2a);

        } else if("In what year were the first Air Jordan sneakers released?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q3b);
            button2.setText(q3a);
            button3.setText(q3c);
            button4.setText(q3d);

            correctAnswer = button2.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q3a);

        } else if("In a bingo game, which number is represented by the phrase “two little ducks”?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q4b);
            button2.setText(q4c);
            button3.setText(q4a);
            button4.setText(q4d);

            correctAnswer = button3.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q4a);


        } else if("According to Greek mythology, who was the first woman on earth?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q5b);
            button2.setText(q5c);
            button3.setText(q5d);
            button4.setText(q5a);

            correctAnswer = button4.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q5a);


        } else if("Samuel Tilden, Grover Cleveland, Al Gore, and Hillary Clinton share what distinction among U.S. presidential candidates?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q6b);
            button2.setText(q6a);
            button3.setText(q6c);
            button4.setText(q6d);

            correctAnswer = button2.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q6a);


        } else if("Which African country was formerly known as Abyssinia?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q7a);
            button2.setText(q7b);
            button3.setText(q7c);
            button4.setText(q7d);

            correctAnswer = button.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q7a);


        } else if("Tennis star Serena Williams won which major tournament while pregnant with her first child?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q8b);
            button2.setText(q8c);
            button3.setText(q8a);
            button4.setText(q8d);

            correctAnswer = button3.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q8a);


        } else if("In which European city would you find Orly airport?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q9b);
            button2.setText(q9a);
            button3.setText(q9c);
            button4.setText(q9d);

            correctAnswer = button2.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q9a);


        } else if("Which singer’s real name is Stefani Joanne Angelina Germanotta?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q10b);
            button2.setText(q10c);
            button3.setText(q10d);
            button4.setText(q10a);

            correctAnswer = button4.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q10a);


        } else if("The only known monotremes in the animal kingdom are the echidna and which other creature?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q11b);
            button2.setText(q11a);
            button3.setText(q11c);
            button4.setText(q11d);

            correctAnswer = button2.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q11a);


        } else if("Kingston, Zuma, and Apollo are the sons of which American female pop star?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q12a);
            button2.setText(q12b);
            button3.setText(q12c);
            button4.setText(q12d);

            correctAnswer = button.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q12a);


        } else if("Fissures, vents, and plugs are all associated with which geological feature?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q13b);
            button2.setText(q13c);
            button3.setText(q13a);
            button4.setText(q13d);

            correctAnswer = button3.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q13a);


        } else if("Which author wrote the ‘Winnie-the-Pooh’ books?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q14b);
            button2.setText(q14c);
            button3.setText(q14d);
            button4.setText(q14a);

            correctAnswer = button4.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q14a);


        } else if("Which Dutch artist painted “Girl with a Pearl Earring”?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q15b);
            button2.setText(q15a);
            button3.setText(q15c);
            button4.setText(q15d);

            correctAnswer = button2.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q15a);


        } else if("Where were the Declaration of Independence, the Constitution, and the Bill of Rights stored during World War II?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q16a);
            button2.setText(q16b);
            button3.setText(q16c);
            button4.setText(q16d);

            correctAnswer = button.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q16a);


        } else if("Which country consumes the most chocolate per capita?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q17b);
            button2.setText(q17c);
            button3.setText(q17a);
            button4.setText(q17d);

            correctAnswer = button3.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q17a);


        } else if("Which two U.S. states don’t observe Daylight Saving Time?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q18b);
            button2.setText(q18a);
            button3.setText(q18c);
            button4.setText(q18d);

            correctAnswer = button2.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q18a);


        } else if("What is the loudest animal on Earth?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q19b);
            button2.setText(q19c);
            button3.setText(q19d);
            button4.setText(q19a);

            correctAnswer = button4.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q19a);


        } else if("What was the first toy to be advertised on television?".equals(randomName)){
            button.setText(q20b);
            button2.setText(q20c);
            button3.setText(q20a);
            button4.setText(q20d);

            correctAnswer = button3.getText().toString();
            a1a.setValue(q20a);


        }

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(correctAnswer.equals(button.getText().toString())){
                    playerScore = +1;
                }
                score1.setValue(playerScore);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("roomName", roomName);
                editor.putString("player", player);
                editor.apply();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity6.class);
                intent.putExtra("roomName", roomName);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(correctAnswer.equals(button2.getText().toString())){
                    playerScore = +1;
                }
                score1.setValue(playerScore);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("roomName", roomName);
                editor.putString("player", player);
                editor.apply();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity6.class);
                intent.putExtra("roomName", roomName);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(correctAnswer.equals(button3.getText().toString())){
                    playerScore = +1;
                }
                score1.setValue(playerScore);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("roomName", roomName);
                editor.putString("player", player);
                editor.apply();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity6.class);
                intent.putExtra("roomName", roomName);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(correctAnswer.equals(button4.getText().toString())){
                    playerScore = +1;
                }
                score1.setValue(playerScore);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("roomName", roomName);
                editor.putString("player", player);
                editor.apply();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity6.class);
                intent.putExtra("roomName", roomName);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        yikes.setValue(randomName);
        textView.setText(randomName);

        executed = true;
    } else if (!player.equals(roomName)){
        System.out.println("activity 5 (q2) loadquestion");

        loadQuestion();
    }

    addRoomsEventListener();

}


private void addRoomsEventListener(){
    messagesRef = database.getReference("/rooms" + "/" + roomName + "/players");
    messagesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // (Portion 1) This portion of the code is connecting the players to the lobby and getting their names from the database
            String search = "/" + roomName;


            first = dataSnapshot.child("/player1").child("/username").getValue(String.class);

            second = dataSnapshot.child("/player2").child("/username").getValue(String.class);

            player1score = dataSnapshot.child("/player1").child("/score").getValue(Integer.class);

            player2score = dataSnapshot.child("/player2").child("/score").getValue(Integer.class);

            if(second == null){
                third = first;

            }else{
                third = first + ", " + second;
            }

            playersInLobbyText = roomName + "Players in Lobby: " + third;
            textView2.setText(playersInLobbyText);


            //The end of portion 1
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //error - nothing
        }
    });
}

private void loadNextQuestion(){
    loadNextQuestion = database.getReference("/rooms" + "/" + roomName + "/questions");
    loadNextQuestion.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
            String questionCounter = dataSnapshot.child("/counter").getValue(String.class);

            if(!player.equals(roomName) && "3".equals(questionCounter)){

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("roomName", roomName);
                editor.putString("player", player);
                editor.apply();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity5.this, MainActivity6.class);
                intent.putExtra("roomName", roomName);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}

private void loadQuestion() {
    loadQuestion = database.getReference("/rooms" + "/" + roomName + "/questions");
    loadQuestion.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
            questionCounter = dataSnapshot.child("/counter").getValue(String.class);

            String a1a;

            if(!player.equals(roomName) && !buttonClicked) {
                String que1 = dataSnapshot.child("/question2" + "/question").getValue(String.class);
                a1a = dataSnapshot.child("/question2" + "/answerA").getValue(String.class);

                textView.setText(que1);


                if ("What is the rarest M and M color?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q1a);
                    button2.setText(q1b);
                    button3.setText(q1c);
                    button4.setText(q1d);

                    correctAnswer = button.getText().toString();

                } else if ("In a website browser address bar, what does “www” stand for?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q2b);
                    button2.setText(q2c);
                    button3.setText(q2d);
                    button4.setText(q2a);

                    correctAnswer = button4.getText().toString();


                } else if ("In what year were the first Air Jordan sneakers released?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q3b);
                    button2.setText(q3a);
                    button3.setText(q3c);
                    button4.setText(q3d);

                    correctAnswer = button2.getText().toString();


                } else if ("In a bingo game, which number is represented by the phrase “two little ducks”?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q4b);
                    button2.setText(q4c);
                    button3.setText(q4a);
                    button4.setText(q4d);

                    correctAnswer = button3.getText().toString();


                } else if ("According to Greek mythology, who was the first woman on earth?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q5b);
                    button2.setText(q5c);
                    button3.setText(q5d);
                    button4.setText(q5a);

                    correctAnswer = button4.getText().toString();


                } else if ("Samuel Tilden, Grover Cleveland, Al Gore, and Hillary Clinton share what distinction among U.S. presidential candidates?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q6b);
                    button2.setText(q6a);
                    button3.setText(q6c);
                    button4.setText(q6d);

                    correctAnswer = button2.getText().toString();


                } else if ("Which African country was formerly known as Abyssinia?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q7a);
                    button2.setText(q7b);
                    button3.setText(q7c);
                    button4.setText(q7d);

                    correctAnswer = button.getText().toString();


                } else if ("Tennis star Serena Williams won which major tournament while pregnant with her first child?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q8b);
                    button2.setText(q8c);
                    button3.setText(q8a);
                    button4.setText(q8d);

                    correctAnswer = button3.getText().toString();


                } else if ("In which European city would you find Orly airport?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q9b);
                    button2.setText(q9a);
                    button3.setText(q9c);
                    button4.setText(q9d);

                    correctAnswer = button2.getText().toString();


                } else if ("Which singer’s real name is Stefani Joanne Angelina Germanotta?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q10b);
                    button2.setText(q10c);
                    button3.setText(q10d);
                    button4.setText(q10a);

                    correctAnswer = button4.getText().toString();


                } else if ("The only known monotremes in the animal kingdom are the echidna and which other creature?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q11b);
                    button2.setText(q11a);
                    button3.setText(q11c);
                    button4.setText(q11d);

                    correctAnswer = button2.getText().toString();


                } else if ("Kingston, Zuma, and Apollo are the sons of which American female pop star?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q12a);
                    button2.setText(q12b);
                    button3.setText(q12c);
                    button4.setText(q12d);

                    correctAnswer = button.getText().toString();


                } else if ("Fissures, vents, and plugs are all associated with which geological feature?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q13b);
                    button2.setText(q13c);
                    button3.setText(q13a);
                    button4.setText(q13d);

                    correctAnswer = button3.getText().toString();


                } else if ("Which author wrote the ‘Winnie-the-Pooh’ books?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q14b);
                    button2.setText(q14c);
                    button3.setText(q14d);
                    button4.setText(q14a);

                    correctAnswer = button4.getText().toString();


                } else if ("Which Dutch artist painted “Girl with a Pearl Earring”?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q15b);
                    button2.setText(q15a);
                    button3.setText(q15c);
                    button4.setText(q15d);

                    correctAnswer = button2.getText().toString();


                } else if ("Where were the Declaration of Independence, the Constitution, and the Bill of Rights stored during World War II?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q16a);
                    button2.setText(q16b);
                    button3.setText(q16c);
                    button4.setText(q16d);

                    correctAnswer = button.getText().toString();


                } else if ("Which country consumes the most chocolate per capita?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q17b);
                    button2.setText(q17c);
                    button3.setText(q17a);
                    button4.setText(q17d);

                    correctAnswer = button3.getText().toString();


                } else if ("Which two U.S. states don’t observe Daylight Saving Time?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q18b);
                    button2.setText(q18a);
                    button3.setText(q18c);
                    button4.setText(q18d);

                    correctAnswer = button2.getText().toString();


                } else if ("What is the loudest animal on Earth?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q19b);
                    button2.setText(q19c);
                    button3.setText(q19d);
                    button4.setText(q19a);

                    correctAnswer = button4.getText().toString();


                } else if ("What was the first toy to be advertised on television?".equals(que1)) {
                    button.setText(q20b);
                    button2.setText(q20c);
                    button3.setText(q20a);
                    button4.setText(q20d);

                    correctAnswer = button3.getText().toString();


                }


                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (correctAnswer.equals(button.getText().toString())) {
                            playerScore = +1;
                        }

                        buttonClicked = true;

                        if ("2".equals(questionCounter)) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity5.this, "Waiting for " + roomName + " to Progress to the Next Question", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            score2.setValue(playerScore);

                        }else{
                            score2.setValue(playerScore);
                            loadNextQuestion();
                        }
                    }
                });
                button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (correctAnswer.equals(button2.getText().toString())) {
                            playerScore = +1;
                        }

                        buttonClicked = true;

                        if ("2".equals(questionCounter)) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity5.this, "Waiting for " + roomName + " to Progress to the Next Question", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            score2.setValue(playerScore);

                        }else{
                            score2.setValue(playerScore);
                            loadNextQuestion();
                        }

                    }
                });
                button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (correctAnswer.equals(button3.getText().toString())) {
                            playerScore = +1;
                        }

                        buttonClicked = true;

                        if ("2".equals(questionCounter)) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity5.this, "Waiting for " + roomName + " to Progress to the Next Question", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            score2.setValue(playerScore);

                        }else{
                            score2.setValue(playerScore);
                            loadNextQuestion();
                        }

                    }
                });
                button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (correctAnswer.equals(button4.getText().toString())) {
                            playerScore = +1;
                        }

                        buttonClicked = true;

                        if ("2".equals(questionCounter)) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity5.this, "Waiting for " + roomName + " to Progress to the Next Question", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            score2.setValue(playerScore);
                        }else{
                            score2.setValue(playerScore);
                            loadNextQuestion();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else if("3".equals(questionCounter) && buttonClicked){
                loadNextQuestion();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //error - nothing
        }
        });
    }

}
```

For the life of me I can't figure this one out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. P.S I am new to android studio + firestore + java, so I am aware that most of the way my code is written could be done better :)

Comment: Does your MainActivity6 opens fine??

Comment: Yep as the player1 initiating, it loads up activity6 just fine. It's only the player2 that is on activity5 and listening for changes that somehow rolls back to activity4 when player1 loads up activity6. there are no callbacks to activity4 within activity6 either.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **700 (seven hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough knowledge and experience to be able to isolate the code further, narrowing it down to this one activity was the most I could do as I don't even really understand the problem all too well. Luckily I'm not too fussed with how long it takes anyone to be able to provide me with some insight. I appreciate your response regardless, thank you :)